# Can I complete the tasks, rocks, and hats after I fight the last boss?

Tags: turnip-boy-robs-a-bank

I still have a few tasks I wanted to complete before finishing the game (getting hats, rocks, and few remaining tasks) but I wanted to make sure the game will still let me do them after performing the following storyline task:

Spoiler:

> attaching rockets to the four corners of the bank and sending it to space.  I presume this is where I fight Stinky to finish the game.

Will the game let me finish everything after I do this last mission or should I do all tasks before I do the mission shown in the spoiler above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are no missable achievements, and the game still goes on after the main mission ending.